# C# code to convert string to Double

Tags: c#, .net, string

I am trying to convert some particular types of strings into double in c#. Normally, Convert.ToDouble() works all great but this one does not always return healthy strings. Which means that input does not always come in format of "4.2". SOmetimes it also comes in form of 4.4.2. Now, i can also not rely on positioning and truncating since it can be 10.11.445 tomorrow?

Any easy and short string manipulation function that I can apply on this scenario?

Comment: Why would you be storing such data as a `double`? ... Store it as a `string` and be done with it.

Comment: What is the expected result for `4.4.2`?

Comment: Expected result for 4.4.2 would be 4.4

Comment: ..and what for `10.11.445`? Is `"tomorrow"` part of that data?

Comment: for 10.11.445 10.11. Just drop everything after second dot

Comment: `4.4.2` is not a valid double, and can't be converted to one. Instead of trying to do that, use it in the datatype appropriate for it (a string). ("How do I convert dog to cat?" is a similar question. The same answer applies: you don't.)

Comment: In addition to what @KenWhite has said.. why would you destroy part of your data (by chopping it off) just so it fits within a given data type? That is almost certainly the wrong way to go about things. As I said.. store it in a `string` and enjoy having all the information you need.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: What if I want to compare the value is it is higher than 4.3 in numeric terms?

Comment: In the format you've given its simply string length _thenby_ content.

Comment: @Californicated because `4.4.2` has absolutely no meaning as a number on the base-10 floating-point number line.  It cannot be compared to `4.3` - the values of the digits don't mean anything until you ascribe something to them.  If you have an idea of what such a value should mean as a base-10 number then you can make your own type and define the rules for conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the posted comments I am assuming you would like to take the string `4.4.2` and convert it to double dropping everything after the second `.` (if found).

A method such as.

```
public static double ConvertStringToDouble(string inputString)
{
    if (inputString.Count(x => x == '.') > 1)
        inputString = inputString.Substring(0, inputString.IndexOf('.', inputString.IndexOf('.') + 1));
    return double.Parse(inputString);
}
```

Comment: This is not exact positioning. This is identifying the position in the string where the second `.` exists (if it exists). How does this differ than your attempt? The only difference you did was go `IndexOf + 1` which will always evaluate to `2`.

Comment: @J I see what you mean now.. thanks for point it out. The answer has been updated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
struct CalifornicatedNumber
{
    private string value;
    public CalifornicatedNumber(string value) 
    { 
       this.value = value; 
    }
    static public implicit operator CalifornicatedNumber(string value) 
    {
       return new CalifornicatedNumber(value);
    }
    static public implicit operator CalifornicatedNumber(double value)
    {
        return new CalifornicatedNumber(value.ToString());
    }
    static public implicit operator double(CalifornicatedNumber calif)
    {                
        return double.Parse(MakeItMakeSense(calif.value));
    }

    static private string MakeItMakeSense(string calif)
    {
        if (calif.Count(x => x == '.') > 1)
          calif = calif.Substring(0, calif.IndexOf('.', calif.IndexOf('.') + 1));
          return calif;
    }            
}
```

then...

```
CalifornicatedNumber califnum;
califnum = "10.11.145";
Console.WriteLine(califnum);
if (califnum > 10) { Console.WriteLine("huzzah");}
califnum = 13.42;
Console.WriteLine(califnum);
if (califnum > 10) { Console.WriteLine("huzzahZah"); }
```

...this is the most foolish piece of code I have ever written.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do what you want according to your comments by parsing either the whole string (if no decimal points) or just the first two parts of the sting if there are multiple decimals.

```
String[] parts = stringVal.Split('.');
double doubleVal;
if (parts.length > 1)
{    
    doubleVal = Convert.ToDouble(parts[0] + "." + parts[1]);
}
else
{
    doubleVale = Convert.ToDouble(stingVal);
}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer so that it actually makes a statement, instead of asking a question? "Try this?" or "How about?" doesn't seem very sure, and code only answers are discouraged here. (See [Is “try this” bad practice?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196187/172661) on [meta] to learn why.)

Comment: Or the single-line version using Linq to gather up to two pieces: `double doubleVal = Convert.ToDouble(string.Join(".", stringVal.Split('.').Take(2)));`;

Answer (score 1):

I would do an approach of creating a bunch of strategies for parsing the input text and then iterating through the strategies until a result is found.

First I'd define a `tryParseDouble` function:

```
Func<string, double?> tryParseDouble = t =>
{
    double value;
    if (double.TryParse(t, out value))
    {
        return value;
    }
    return null;
};
```

Then I'd create my list of strategies:

```
var strategies = new Func<string, double?>[]
{
    t =>
    {
        var parts = t.Split('.');
        return parts.Length > 1
            ? tryParseDouble(String.Join(".", parts.Take(2)))
            : null;
    },
    tryParseDouble,
    t => null,
};
```

And finally I'd get the result:

```
var text = "4.4.2";

var result =
    strategies
        .Select(p => p(text))
        .Where(v => v != null)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

The `result` variable is a `double?` with the value parsed or a `null` if none of the strategies work. The final strategy, `t => null`, is there to be explicit but is not necessary in getting the final null result.

As new strategies are needed to parse different types of input text they can just be added to the list as needed.